# The map $A \to A'$ is a linear isometry from $B(X,Y) \to B(Y',X')$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces. Show that the map $A \to A'$ is a linear isometry from $B(X,Y) \to B(Y',X')$.

$A'$ is the dual of $A$.

Need some hints for the problem.

Comment: What is your definition of $B(\cdot,\cdot)$?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the norm on the dual of a normed vector space $X$ is given (for $L\in X^\star$) by:
$$ \Vert L \Vert_{X^\star} = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert_X \leq 1} \vert L(x) \vert.$$

Let

$$H: L(X,Y) \rightarrow L(Y^\star, X^\star), A \mapsto \left(A^\star: B \mapsto B\circ A\right).$$

One easily checks that this is a linear map. Using the definition of the operator norm and the norm on the dual of $X$, we get for $A\in L(X,Y)$
$$ \Vert H(A) \Vert_{L(Y^\star, X^\star)}  
= \sup_{\Vert B \Vert_{Y^\star}\leq 1, \ \Vert x \Vert_X \leq 1} \vert (B \circ A)(x) \vert \leq \Vert A \Vert_{L(X,Y)} .$$

Now use the Hahn-Banach Theorem zu construct a suitable sequence $(B_n)_{n\geq 1} \subseteq Y^\star$ to prove

$$ \Vert H (A) \Vert_{L(Y^\star, X^\star)} \geq \Vert A \Vert_{L(X,Y)}$$

and conclude that $H$ is an isometry.

Comment: A small point, but really once you have shown $\|H\|\le1$ and $\|H(A)\|\ge\|A\|$, then you conclude $\|H(A)\|=\|A\|$ i.e. $H$ is an isometry. Merely deducing $\|H\|=1$ is not sufficient.

Comment: @Jason Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T:B(X,Y) \rightarrow B(Y',X')$ such that $T(A)=A'$

*Hint*

You can prove that the norm of the operator $A$ in $B(X,Y)$ equals  the norm of $A'$ in $B(Y',X')$.

For this you can use the Hahn-Banach Theorem.